# Copy data from one list to another while formatting it in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a class shown below:

```cs
public class BidCostModel {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal? Month1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Month2 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Month3 { get; set; }       
}
```

I created a list of it and filled it with some data using EF:

```
List<BidCostModel> list1 = new List<BidCostModel>();
fillOperation(data);
```

I have another class with similar property name but different data type

```cs
public class BidCostModelFormatted {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Month1 { get; set; }
    public string Month2 { get; set; }
    public string Month3 { get; set; }        
}

List<BidCostModelFormatted> list2 = new List<BidCostModelFormatted>();
```

I want to copy data from `list1` into `list2` while adding thousand separators. Is there a mapping tool or something that I can use without doing a `foreach` loop to add thousand separators while copying the data into `list2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need rely on some external tool. Even with a tool you need to define "formatted" class and configure tool to format certain properties.

Create a class which will be responsible to "format" values

```
public class BidCostFormatted
{
    private readonly BidCostModel _model;
    public string Code => _model.Code;
    public string Month1 => _model.Month1.ForView();
    public string Month2 => _model.Month2.ForView();
    public string Month3 => _model.Month3.ForView();  

    public BidCostFormatted(BidCostModel model) => _model = model;       
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ForView(this decimal? value)
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
        {
            return value.Value.ToString("N");
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then formatting would be easy and maintainable

```
var formattedBidCosts = 
    bidCosts.Select(cost => new BidCostFormatted(cost)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps format the original values with `ToString("N")` and append it to the new list:

```
list2.AddRange(
    list1.Select(
        a => {
            b = new BidCostModelFormatted();
            b.Code = a.Code;
            b.Month1 = a.Month1.ToString("N");
            b.Month2 = a.Month2.ToString("N");
            b.Month3 = a.Month3.ToString("N");
            return b;
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in just two lines, then serialize the first list to JSON and then desirialize it to the list of the second class, it will work.